# How to send name of the image clicked to the next php page?

Tags: php, html, post, get, session-variables

I am making a website for movie ticket booking , I have added several images of the movie posters in the landing page. I wanted to make it as when the user clicks on the image of a particular movie poster it displays the name of the movie on the next webpage. So the problem is I don't know know how to send the name of the movie the user has clicked on to the next page through php with or without using the form tag.?

I have tried by giving the images of the posters ID's as the movie name and retrieve the name of the movie from the ID as-:

```
<?php
   $name = $_POST['Name']
?>
```

here 'Name' is the name of the movie given as the ID of the image in html

but this does not work!`

Comment: Your database should have an auto-increment ID column in your database instead of using the name, because two movies could theoretically have the same name.

Answer (score 1):

If the user is only clicking on a link then the general approach is to put a query string value on that link.

For example:

```
<a href="movie.php?id=123">your image here</a>
```

Then in `movie.php` you'd get the "123" value with:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
```

And you'd query your database (or wherever you store your data) using that `$id` value to get the specific record you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I have created you a simple demo for what you are asking using good php security. You can take what I have done here and improve on it however you like. I have made the code as simple as possible.

The premise of this code is based on security. For something like this always pass an id / number in the query string and access your data like this: 
test.php?id=3

 I will keep your code secure and easy to manage.

Create a file named test.php and add the below code

```
<?php
// create array of movie posters, 
// you can also get the list of posters from a database and loop over them the same way
$movie_poster[1] = ['image' => 'image_1.jpg', 'title' => 'Forest Gump'];
$movie_poster[2] = ['image' => 'image_2.jpg', 'title' => 'Lord of the Rings'];
$movie_poster[3] = ['image' => 'image_3.jpg', 'title' => 'Mission impossible'];
$movie_poster[4] = ['image' => 'image_4.jpg', 'title' => 'Indiana Jones'];

// check if user clicked on image
// for security purposes we check if variable is set then
// convert it to an integer. If it is not a number it will equal 0.
// This is for security purposes.
if (isset($_GET['id']) && (int)$_GET['id'] != 0) {
    // user clicked so we display title of image
    $id = (int)$_GET['id']; // convert to integer/number for security
    ?>
    <h1><?php echo $movie_poster[$id]['title']; ?></h1>
    <?php
}

// display the images on the page
foreach ($movie_poster as $id => $mp) {
    ?>
        <div>
            <a href="test.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>">
                <img src="<?php echo $mp['image']; ?>" />
                <br /><?php echo $mp['title']; ?>
            </a>
        </div>
    <?php
}
```